# MySQL installation on Mac isn't working

Tags: mysql, database, installation, database-administration

I just installed mysql on my Mac per [these instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/macosx-installation-pkg.html).  However, at the command line `which mysql` and `which mysqld` replies nothing.

How do I get from the above link to [this tutorial link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connecting-disconnecting.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely, the installer didn't add a path entry for the newly installed binaries, and since they are not in a standard path, `which` can't find them.

Try if calling `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql` works. If yes, add the following line to the file `/etc/profile`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

If not, you have to find out where the binaries landed and alter the above line accordingly.

After that, you have to restart Terminal.app before the changes will take effect.